# Is there a limit to the number of item in inventory?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm wondering if there is a limit to the weight one's character can have in it's inventory. In the character status page I can see that there is a limit to the weight of the equipment, but I don't find one for the inventory. Can I carry each and every item I find?

If there is a limit, what is it? Where can I find it? Does it depends on character's stats (strength)? Is there a NPC that can store the items I want to keep, but can't carry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only limit on your inventory is that you can only hold 99 copies of each stackable
 item.

Comment: If I pickup a duplicate weapon, many ennemies drop Long Swords, they do not stack. Can I also hold 99 copies of those items too?

Comment: @SylvainDefresne There would be no limit. The limit only applies to stackable items (see my edit)

Comment: @Wipqozn, are you sure there is no limit? The Dark Souls strategy guide states that the max load is 1984 items.

Comment: @Kotsu I'm fairly certain, although if the guide says otherwise I become more doubtful.

Answer (score 7):

There doesn't seems to be a limit in the weight of the items you have in your inventory, however there is a limit of 1984 items in total, not counting keys and scrolls. For stackable items, there is a limit of 99 copies of each stackable item.

There are however many different items, including many weapons and piece of armor. Keeping all of them in your inventory at all time can make switching of equipement difficult. The merchant *Domhnall of Zena* that is located in the *Depth* sell a item called *Bottomless Box*. It has the following in-game description:

> A peculiar bottomless wooden box.
>   Its origins are unknown. Some deride
>   it as a symbol of unbridled avarice.
>   
>   Any number of items can be deposited into
>   the box, and items can be managed while
>   resting at a bonfire.

It allow you to store item in the box at each bonfire instead of carrying them with you. So if there is any limit to your inventory, you can bypass it via this item. And if you want to keep all the stuff you find, but like to switch of gear depending on the situation, this may be the solution to your problems.

Comment: Your answer is more accurate than the accepted one, but you should note that some items can have more than 99 copies of a stackable item for ammunition.

Comment: Also I'm currently studying the save file, and items start at offset 0x2e0 and end at offset 0xe2e0, which means there is 0xe000 items structures. Since there are 7 elements in this structure, there is a maximum of 0x2000 items, which is 8192