# Selling items in dark souls

Tags: dark-souls

I've been grinding my character a fair bit, and as a result I have ended up with a fair few number of longswords, battleaxes, hollow armours, etc. I was wondering if there is any way of selling these items?

In terms of progress I'm at the dragon guarding the bridge, and I am attempting to obtain the drake sword.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an NPC, *Kingseeker Frampt*, that will consume your items in exchange for souls. He appears near the *Firelink Shrine* after you have rung the two bells. So yes, there is a way to sell item, but not until later in the game.

However, there is almost no limit to the number of items you can have in your inventory (see this question [Is there a limit to the number of item in inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33662/5133)). You can hold up to 1984 different items in your inventory, and if you purchase the *Bottomless Box*, from a merchant in the *Depth*, you can store all those items in it and have a manageable inventory.

However, I think you should just drop the duplicate items because the resell value is really low. This table, from [one of the Dark Souls wiki](http://darksoulswiki.wikispaces.com/Kingseeker+Frampt), shows how many souls you'll gain from each class of item:

```
Weapons                    50
Armor                      100
Dung Pie                   200
Cracked Red Eye Orb        500
Copper Coin                1000
Some unique items          5000
```

Even if you resell 1000 longswords, you'll only gain 50000 souls. Compared to the time it will take you to sell all of them, and to manage your inventory, I think it is not a good trade-off. There are quicker ways farm souls.

During your second play through, reselling some of the unique items may be a cheap way to get some souls. However, reselling basic items does not seem interesting to me.

Comment: Some of the unique weapons and armors sell for 5000 souls. But you probably don't want to cash those in on your first playthrough.

Comment: So what is the point of being able to "sell" items?  It almost sounds like the dev threw it in to satisfy people's complaints?  Just my theory... I haven't gotten that far in the game yet.