# What does the copper coin do in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

The guy who you can buy miracles from and who later has a small mission just gave me a copper coin. He didn't say what it's for and its item description didn't help. Does anyone have any idea as to what this does?

Comment: Extremely closely related: [Selling items in dark souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/33793/124566)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copper coin can be "sold"(fed) to Kingseeker Frampt for 1,000 souls.  It doesn't have any other use

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. Though i have yet to meet this  kingseeker frampt, im sure to meet him soon. By the by, i dont suppose you could clarify what you mean by “fed”?          It just seems strange to feed a coin do a fellow human and not recieve deadly retribution for choking a man to death.

Comment: Frampt is a giant serpent who appears after ringing both of the bells.  He plays an important role in the lore, and can also be fed unwanted gear in exchange for souls.  This is the only way to 'sell' gear to an NPC in Dark Souls.